# Xamarin forms debugging asp.net web Api 2

Tags: xamarin.forms

Is it possible to debug a xamarin forms calling an asp.net web api2?

I know it can be done with asp.net core but what about if you are stuck on a webapi2?

I basically want to step into a webapi2 when using a xamarin forms

Any suggestions

Comment: are projects in same solution?

Comment: @EhsanVali there are not but could be. Not sure it matters . Please expand

Comment: do you want to debug both project at the same time?

Comment: yes I want to debug both project at the same time

Answer (score 0):

Web Api and client execute at separate process and you cannot step from one to another one with same debugger.
so, if both projects is in one solution fallow these steps

1. right click on solution
2. click properties
3. select "multiple startup projects"
4. set "action" property of both client and server to "start"
5. run projects and debug it

if projects are not in same solution, open every project on separate instance of visual studio and run both

Comment: that just does not work I wish it was that simple

Comment: I use this way now. what is the problem?